# C# method resolution with generic and type inference

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, method-resolution-order

I was surprised today by the way the method resolution works.

Here's the code as an exemple :

```
class Program
{
    static class Mapper<TSource, TTarget>
    {
        public static void Map<TMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> source, Expression<Func<TTarget, TMember>> target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }

        public static void Map<TMember, TSourceCollection>(Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceCollection>> source, Expression<Func<TTarget, TMember[]>> target)
            where TSourceCollection : IEnumerable<TMember>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public byte[] prop { get; set; }
    }

    class B
    {
        public byte[] prop { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper<A, B>.Map(x => x.prop, x => x.prop);
    }
}
```

As you see the method Map has two overloads, one when the type of the properties are the same, and one when the source property is an enumerable and the right property is an array.

Then when i call the method with an array on both sides it calls the second overload, but as the types are exactly the same i expected the first overload to be called.

I thought the first overload would have a better scoring because it depends on fewer generic arguments than the second, and it fits better with the types of the arguments i pass to the method.

Can someone explain why the compiler chooses to call the second overload instead of the first one please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You call the mapper with a class A, and B, which are not arrays. They both have a property that is a byte array, but they are not the same type.

Comment: Change byte[] to int and the first one is used. So I guess it is because a byte array is an IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks but the resolution should occur on TMember, not TSource or TTarget. The TSource and TTarget are different by nature.

Comment: Yes, byte array and IEnumerable are compatible. Clearly both overloads can work but why choose the second one when the first one says "if both are the same take me". In my exemple both are byte[] so i expected the first one to be chosen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload resolution is complicated and you can read the spec to understand why. One thing I am pretty sure of though is that it doesn't consider the need to specify less generic parameters when considering which overload is better (though it will take non-generic over generic but when both are generic it considers them equal).

When looking at the overloads it can choose from they are all equal apart from whether the second parameter is `TMember` or `TMember[]`.

The spec talks a lot about choosing the most specific member and I can't work out which part is actually applicable here (there are many places where it talks about preferring X over Y when X is more specific). I would have thought it was either Section 7.6.5.1 (of the c#5 spec) which is where it constructs a candidate list or section 7.5.3 where it deals with overload resolution. However the former doesn't seem to exclude either method overload and the latter to my reading only deals with the parameters after the generic ones have been substituted in at which point they are identical. It may be that there is somewhere else in the spec that deals with this (eg when it infers the type arguments).

In woolly terms though I believe that the compiler is considering that `TMember[]` is more specific than `TMember`. This can be broadly seen to be true because `TMember` will accept more things than TMember[] will so `TMember[]` is more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The matching of first method `TMember` and second method `TSourceCollection` is of equal value for any type that satisfies the `where TSourceCollection : IEnumerable<TMember>` condition.

The type `TMember[]` is a more detailed type match for `byte[]` compared to `TMember`. So this should be the point where the second method scores better than the first. Consequently, this 'better' match outrules the fact, that method two has more generic parameters.